# Ridgelet and Curvelet image processing package

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working in image processing and I want to use ridgelet and curvelet transforms. Please could any one tell me about a good and tested package for such job. I tried the known "BeamLab" package but it seems that it does not work on windows 7 ". I tried the FastRidgeletTransform function and it gave me the error:

"Invalid MEX-file  'D:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\BeamLab200\MEXSource\RidgeMEXSource\PseudopolarFFT_c.dll':
D:\Program
Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\BeamLab200\MEXSource\RidgeMEXSource\PseudopolarFFT_c.dll
is not a valid Win32 application."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For curvelet I stronlgy recommend CurveLab (http://www.curvelet.org/software.html).Although you will have to apply for a commercial license if you plan using it commercially.

The problem you are facing with BeamLab is probably caused by a difference in CPU architecture of your MATLAB installation and BeamLab dlls. If you are using MatLab 64 bits for example you cannot use 32 bits version of BeamLab dlls.